# Gibt es ein Minimalpaar für die beiden deutschen ch-Laute (ç und χ)?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-sounds

Ich suche (aus reiner Neugierde) zwei deutsche Worte, deren Aussprache sich nur durch einen Austausch der folgenden beiden Laute unterscheidet:

- [χ] – *ch* wie in *Bach, Buch, doch*
- [ç] – *ch* wie in *ich, Blech, euch, Mädchen*

Da es im Deutschen größtenteils vom vorhergenden Laut abhängt, ob ein *ch* [χ] oder [ç] ausgesprochen wird, ist dies nicht so trivial. Ein vielversprechender Weg ist das Diminutivsuffix *-chen,* das immer [çən] ausgesprochen wird.

Ein paar Beispiele, die dem Gesuchten sehr nahe kommen, sind:

- *Frauchen* (Hundebesitzerin) [fʀaʊ̯çən] und *[fauchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fauchen)* [faʊ̯χən]. Hier unterscheidet sich nur die eingängliche Konsonantenfolge.
- *Pochen* (kleiner Po)  [poːçən] und pochen (klopfen) [pɔχən]. Hier unterscheidet sich der Vokal.

Anmerkungen:

- Ich unterscheide für diese Frage dabei nicht zwischen einem vokalischen *n* und Schwa + *n* in Reduktionssilben. Zum Beispiel sehe ich [poːçən] und [ˈpɔχn̩] als äquivalent an. (Analog es gilt für ähnliche Fälle.)
- Es ist mir nicht wichtig, ob ein derartiges Beispiel linguistisch als [Minimalpaar](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalpaar) klassifiziert wird.
- Erschwerend kommt hinzu, dass *a, o* und *u* – also die Vokale, auf die normalerweise ein [χ] folgt – bei der Diminuitivbildung meistens umgelautet werden. Es gibt aber Ausnahmen wie *Frauchen, Rosinchen* oder *Katerchen.*
- Wenn vor die Wahl gestellt, bevorzuge ich »natürlichere« Antworten.

Comment: Würde Dir abgesehen von mangelnder Natürlichkeit die amerikanisch beeinflusste Variante "Machen" von "Mamalein" genügen?

Comment: Wahrscheinlich wirst du das nicht durchgehen lassen, aber beispielsweise spreche ich ein "r" häufig als [χ] aus, zum Beispiel in Sport. (Ist das eigentlich mein Dialekt oder eine falsche Angewohnheit einzig von mir?) Naja, auf jeden Fall spreche ich den "Wirt" auch mit [χ]. Einziges Problem nun eigentlich ist, dass ich den "Wicht" ausspreche, als wäre es ein "sch". Naja... ich denke, du hättest es eh nicht durchgehen lassen :p

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Es ist eine Antwort, aber ja, »natürlichere« Antworten wären mir lieber.

Comment: Eine Richtung, in die man suchen könnte, wären Wörter, die ein *-arch-* und ein *-ach-* enthalten. Ein *r* nach Vokal wird oft zu einem Reduktionslaut (umgedrehtes *a* in IPA); ein *a* per se mit diesem nachfolgenden Reduktionslaut klingt dann oft wie ein langes *a*. (Zugegebenermaßen reden wir hier dann nicht mehr von Phonemen.)

Comment: Z.B. gibt es den Fluss "Ache" und das Schiff "Arche".

Comment: Ein paar (umgangssprachlich ausgesprochen fast) passende Kandidaten, die mir spontan einfallen: "Fauchen" (Dim. vom Vogel (P)fau) und "fauchen" (sich gereizt äußern)?  "plärren" (lautstark reden) und "blechen" (Geld ausgeben)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drei Vorschläge, allerdings jeweils ziemlich "herbeikonstruiert" mit Deiner Idee des Diminutivs "-chen":

- die Stadt Aachen und Achen als Diminutiv zu [A](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/a_Buchstabe_Ton)
- tauchen und [Tauchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tau_Seil)
- Kuchen und [Kuhchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kuh)

Eine [Google-Suche nach *Kuhchen*](https://www.google.de/search?pws=0&hl=de&q=kuhchen&nfpr=1&sa=X) fördert noch einige interessante Seiten zu Tage, so zum Beispiel [eine *Kuhchen* benannte Plastik](http://www.bildhauervogler.de/Projekte/Kuhchen/kuhchen_1.html) und [das Buch "Volkstümliches in Ostpreußen"](http://books.google.de/books?id=7Dk3Mv3JOy4C&pg=RA2-PA158&lpg=RA2-PA158&dq=kuhchen&source=bl&ots=yqQYhiqW3B&sig=PgdDmZvTB7thuILp_m-HYlrk2n0&hl=de&sa=X&ei=M1dNVMP5GMHtO4vogMAD&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBzgU#v=onepage&q=kuhchen&f=false), in dem mehrfach *Kuhchen* verwendet wird, sowie ab etwa Seite 3 auch einige sprachwissenschaftliche Arbeiten auf Google Books, die das Thema der Frage diskutieren oder zumindest streifen.

Comment: Müssten die Diminuitive nicht Umlaute enthalten?

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Jein. Es gibt Diminutive ohne Umlautung *(Frauchen, Katerchen, Rosinchen).* Beim ersten Beispiel wäre es sehr sinnvoll, nicht umzulauten. Beim zweiten Beispiel ist es zumindest nicht abwegig (vgl. *Frauchen)* – wenn man mal von der Alternative *Seil* absieht. Beim dritten Beispiel fände ich auch die Umlautung näherliegend, da hier ja selbst der Plural Umlaute enthält.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Sehe ich ähnlich. Wobei der Duden sowohl _Schuhchen_ als auch _Schühchen_ kennt und ich deshalb auch _Kuhchen_ nicht abwegig fände. Ich bin offenbar auch längst nicht der erste, dem _Kuhchen_ einfällt - siehe die Ergänzung meiner Antwort.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Das erste Beispiel habe ich ehrlich gesagt nicht beachtet. Hier ist "Achen" wohl sinnvoller (sofern man dies von Buchstäbchen behaupten kann). Kuhchen klingt furchtbar unnatürlich, und sieht auch so aus. Außerdem muss man sich sehr dazu zwingen, das "ch" weich auszusprechen. Bei "Tauchen" greift derselbe Einwand - jener, der mit dem Hauptproblem dieser Minimalpaarsuche einhergeht.

Answer (score 6):

Ich glaube nicht, dass es so ein Minimalpaar gibt. Das liegt daran, dass - wie ich glaube - [χ] und [ç] Allophone desselben deutschen Phonems sind. Ob [χ] oder [ç] gesprochen wird, hängt von dem Vokal vor dem Frikativ ab, bzw davon, ob davor überhaupt ein Vokal steht oder nicht.

Meiner Beobachtung nach ist es so, dass bei einem bestimmten Wort [χ] bzw. [ç] niemals durch den jeweils anderen Laut ausgetauscht wird, was eigentlich dafür spricht, dass es sich um unterschiedliche Phoneme handelt.

Andererseits folgt auf i nie [χ] sondern immer [ç], während es bei u genau umgekehrt ist. Ersetzt man in »Wicht« das i durch u (»Wucht«) wird aus dem [ç] automatisch ein [χ]. Das spricht dafür, dass [χ] und [ç] zwei Allophone desselben Phonems sind.

Comment: Das war mir weitestgehend bewusst bzw. worauf ich mich mit Folgendem bezog: »Da es im Deutschen größtenteils vom vorhergenden Laut abhängt, ob ein ch [χ] oder [ç] ausgesprochen wird, ist dies nicht so trivial.« Andererseits habe ich ja auch erläutert, wieso es dennoch gehen könnte, und ein paar Beispiele genannt, die dem Gesuchten sehr nahe kommen.

Comment: »Meiner Beobachtung nach ist es so, dass bei einem bestimmten Wort [χ] bzw. [ç] niemals durch den jeweils anderen Laut ausgetauscht wird […]« – Je nachdem, was jetzt als »ein bestimmtes Wort« fasst, könnten dem *breche/brich/brach* oder *brauchte/bräuchte* widersprechen.

Comment: »Breche«, »brich« und »brach« verstehe ich aber als drei verschiedene Wörter. Leider ist der Begriff »Wort« nicht exakt definiert. Fachsprachlich sind es verschiedene Wortformen desselben Lexems.

Answer (score 1):

eine Arche - viele Archen

In die Stadt Aachen fließt leider kein Fluss, sonst könnte man mit diesen Archen nach Aachen fahren.

Archen /aɐҫn/ - Aachen /ɑ:xn/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Nach meinem Verständnis KANN es in der deutschen Sprache ein solches Minimalpaar nicht geben, da es klaren Richtlinien unterliegt, wann Ch1 bzw. Ch2 artikuliert wird.

Ch1 folgt grundsätzlich auf "i", "e", "ei" und "eu".
Ch2 folgt grundsätzlich auf "a", "o", "u" und "au".

Da es also vom vorausgehenden Laut eines Wortes abhängt, ob ch1 oder ch2 artikuliert wird, kann es kein solches Minimalpaar geben.

Comment: Wie bereits in der Frage erwähnt, bin ich mir der von Dir angeführten Regeln durchaus bewusst, aber sie sind eben nicht völlig ohne Ausnahme: So folgt zum Beispiel im Wort *Frauchen* ([fʀaʊ̯çən]) Dein ch₁ ([ç]) auf *au.*

Comment: Im Beispiel Frauchen gehört das ch nicht zum Wortstamm , steht daher im Silbenanlaut und ist insofern auch keine Ausnahme.

Comment: Ich weiß, und genau nach solchen Fällen (o. Ä.) habe ich gefragt.

Comment: Im Beispiel Frauchen gehört das ch nicht zum Wortstamm, steht im Silbenanlaut des Diminutivsuffix (in dieser Verkleinerungsform IMMER als ch1) und ist insofern auch keine Ausnahme. Trotzdem muss ich sagen, dass ich an solche Möglichkeiten nicht gedacht habe. Vielleicht findest du ja so etwas Brauchbares.

Comment: Genau, und all das steht bereits in der Frage.

Answer (score -2):

Was ist mit dich und Dach? Ich hab nicht viel Erfahrung mit Phonem-Untersuchungen, weil Phoneme für mich kein großes Problem sind. Daher weiß ich nicht, ob dich und Dach als ein "Minimalpaar" angesehen werden. Oder: mich und mach'. Schlucht und schlicht, Gericht und gerecht, Gesicht und gedacht, siech und such', Rechen und Rachen.

Comment: Hier ist der Unterschied zu groß, da ja auch noch ein *i* gegen ein *a* getauscht wird. Außerdem hatte ich zumindest gehofft, dass die Frage auch verständlich ist, wenn man nicht weiß, was ein Minimalpaar ist.