# Minimalpaar h ↔︎ ch

Tags: pronunciation

Ein Minimalpaar ist ein Paar, das aus zwei sehr ähnlichen Wörtern besteht, die sich in der Aussprache nur durch einen einzigen Laut unterscheiden. Beispielsweise unterscheidet sich die Paare

> Kiste = [ˈkɪstə] ↔︎ Küste = [ˈkʏstə]
> Mutter = [ˈmʊtɐ] ↔︎ Mütter = [ˈmʏtɐ]

jeweils nur durch den ersten Vokal, und beide Paare zusammen belegen, dass der Laut [ʏ] (kurzes Ü) im Deutschen weder durch ein [ɪ] (kurzes I) noch durch ein [ʊ] (kurzes U) ersetzt werden kann, weil es sonst zu Verwechslungen kommt.

In einer [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/64670/1487), die hier vor kurzem gestellt wurde, ging der Fragesteller von der falschen Prämisse aus, dass der Digraph *»ch«* im Deutschen oftmals wie *»h«* auszusprechen sei. In meiner Antwort habe ich gezeigt, dass es für *»ch«* zwar sechs verschiedene Aussprachemöglichkeiten<sup>1</sup> gibt, dass darunter aber [h] (wie in *»Hase«* oder *»Hut«*) nicht vorkommt. Ich hätte meine Antwort gerne um ein Minimalpaar ergänzt, das belegt, dass das Ersetzen vor allem von [x], [χ] und [ç] durch [h] zu Verwechslungen führen kann, aber ich kann kein solches Minimalpaar finden.

Die konkrete Frage:
Gibt es im Deutschen Minimalpaare für die Lautpaare [h]↔︎[x]/[χ] und [h]↔︎[ç]?

(Minimalpaare für [x]↔︎[ç] wurden bereits [in dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/17436/1487) behandelt.)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[x] oder [χ] in *»ach«;* [ç] in *»ich«;* [k] in *»Chor«;* [ʃ] in *»Chef«* und [t͡ʃ] in *»Chip«*</sub>

Comment: Wie wichtig sind Dir die entsprechenden Laute? [h] wird außer am Anfang des Wortes ja (immer?) verschluckt (außer von Grundschullehrern), während [χ] nicht am Wortanfang vorkommt und [ç] sehr selten ist. Ansonsten kannst Du sowas wie *Reihen/Reichen* nehmen. In ersterem taucht zwar eigentlich kein [h] auf, aber jeder wird [ʁaɪ̯hən] als *Reihen* und nicht als *Reichen* verstehen, was ja letztlich Dein Argument ist.

Comment: *Hemisphäre* vs. *Chemie-Sphäre* möglicherweise. Die beiden Wörter sind aber nicht sehr deutsch...

Comment: Ich *beherberge* ganze *Becherberge*. Wollte es nur gesagt haben.

Answer (score 3):

Die Behauptung, es könne gar keine Minimalpaare geben, ist falsch. Bekanntlich (aber leider immer noch oft ignoriert) ist Deutsch eine plurizentrische Sprache. Deutsch wird also je nach Region anders ausgesprochen. In einigen Regionen mag es tatsächlich keine Minimalpaare mit /x/ und /h/ geben, doch in anderen Regionen gibt es sie durchaus.

Im Schweizer Hochdeutschen können Minimalpaare wie die folgenden vorkommen:

- Chorus /ˈxoːrʊs/ – Horus /ˈhoːrʊs/
- Chöre /ˈxøːrɛ/ – höre /ˈhørɛ/
- Rache /ˈraːxɛ/ – Rahe /ˈraːhɛ/
- Nachen /ˈnaːxən/ – nahen /ˈnaːhən/

Answer (score 0):

Ein paar Worte die mir dazu einfallen (und ich greife das Beispiel von Wrzlprmft mal mit auf)

> Leihen ↔︎ Leichen/laichen
> Reihen ↔︎ reichen
> sahen ↔︎ Sachen
> Weiher ↔︎ weicher

Comment: Bei leihen/leichen/laichen hatten wir wohl den gleichen Einfall. *sa-hen/Sach-en* ist mit Vorsicht zu genießen, da es sich um verschiedene Wortarten und eine unterschiedliche Morphemstruktur handelt, bei der die Minimalität eines Minimalpaares nicht mehr gegeben ist. Ebenso bei *Wei-her* (mit i.d.R. stummen *h*) und dem Derivativum *weich-er*.

Comment: In allen genannten Vorschlägen ist das H stumm: »leihen« und »Leihen« = [ˈlaɪ̯ən] oder  [laɪ̯n]. »Leihe« = [ˈlaɪ̯ə], »reihen« und »Reihen« = [ˈʁaɪ̯ən]. Ebenso »nahen« =  [ˈnaːən], »sahen« = [ˈzaːən] und »Weiher« = [ˈvaɪ̯ɐ]. Keines der genannten Paare ist daher ein Minimalpaar für [h]↔︎[ç].

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das ist so nicht richtig, die Antwort geht auf diesen Punkt ausführlich mit Belegen ein (weshalb mich die erneute Feststellung des bereits Festgestellten überrascht). Das *h* wurde vor wenigen Jahrzehnten regelhaft mitgesprochen und ist heute noch eine mögliche Aussprachevariante. Durch den Wegfall hat sich nichts an der Phonemstuktur des Deutschen geändert, oder wäre das dein Argument? Zudem hätte ein Minimalpaar mit Nullphonem zumindest indizielle Wirkung.

Comment: Das einzige dieser Wörter, wo das H historisch gerechtfertigt ist und somit früher ausgesprochen wurde, ist _sahen._ Es bildet aber gerade kein Minimalpaar mit _Sachen,_ denn der Vokal ist nicht derselbe: _sahen_ hat ein langes /aː/, _Sachen_ hingegen ein kurzes /a/.